# Equations relating combinations

Tags: combinations

Suppose that **a**, **b**, and **c** are integer numbers, and that there are **a** many unique combinations of length **b**, where each constituent of the combination has **c** permutations, and suppose that combinations which would be the same if not for being in a different order are ignored as duplicates (e.g. where d, e, and f are constituents of a combination, combination def would be thrown out as a duplicate of fed but fed would be still  be considered). What are the equations which relate **a**, **b**, and **c**?

Comment: I've made some changes, I hope it is a little clearer now. I'm not the best at explaining.

Comment: Combinations are generally combinations **of some things.** What things are you putting into whatever you think a “combination of length $b$” is? Are you making combinations of the letters $d,e,f$ only? What are examples of some of the $c$ permutations of one of these constituents? As far as I know, the letter $d$ has only one permutation.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to give a very concrete example of what you’re doing: pick a small number $b$ and write out a list of every unique combination of length $b.$ Then write out a list of all $c$ permutations of whatever it is you’re permuting. Then people might be able to see what you mean. Right now I think the technical words are getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you considering combinations and permutations of $b$ distinct objects from a total of $N$ distinct objects? If so:-

$a=\begin{pmatrix} N \\ b  \end{pmatrix}$ and $c=b!$